# Capybara expect BEFORE ajax request completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

Here is short flow of my form:

1. You click Submit button
2. Submit button gets disabled
3. AJAX request is sent to API.
4. AJAX response is received.
5. Button is clickable again.

> ```
> scenario 'user can not resubmit form before API response' do
>   expect(find_button('Submit')[:disabled]).to be_falsey
>   click_button 'Submit'
>   expect(find_button('Submit')[:disabled]).not_to be_falsey
>   ## Here ajax response is received
>   expect(find_button('Submit')[:disabled]).to be_falsey
> end
> ```

This test actually passes but I feel I have no control over it and I'm not concerned if it really test what I intended.

Is there any way to have more control over AJAX responses? Does this test actually test feature I described?

#### edit:

this test actually randomly fails/passes. I guess it is caused by executing `expect(find_button('Submit')[:disabled]).not_to be_falsey` after AJAX call

Comment: It isn't necessary to tell us you edited or updated your question. Once we hit a certain level we can see the revision history and can tell what changed when. Instead, simply add your new content where it should occur in the document according to grammar and the flow of the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Automatically wait for AJAX with Capybara](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara)

```
# spec/support/wait_for_ajax.rb
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
end
```

Usage:

```
scenario 'user can not resubmit form before API response' do
  expect(find_button('Submit')[:disabled]).to be_falsey
  click_button 'Submit'
  expect(find_button('Submit')[:disabled]).not_to be_falsey
  wait_for_ajax
  expect(find_button('Submit')[:disabled]).to be_falsey
end
```

> The helper uses the jQuery.active variable, which tracks the number of
>   active AJAX requests. When it’s 0, there are no active AJAX requests,
>   meaning all of the requests have completed.

Comment: I'm using angular :/ I believe `Jquery.active` isn't a solution

Comment: Also - I made logic mistake inside my code. AJAX comes between last two lines. Your script just ensure that no AJAX are left. I want to ensure that AJAX requests are still there. 

I changed question title - it was a bit misleading

Comment: @FilipBartuzi maybe you can call `$http.pendingRequests.length` ?

Answer (score 0):

The test is not testing what you want because you're querying for the disabled attribute outside the finder which means Capybaras retrying behavior can't work. Instead you want to use the disabled option to the finder

```
expect(find_button('Submit', disabled: false)).to be
click...
expect(find_button('Submit', disabled: true)).to be
...
```

This way Capybara can retry the find until it passes (or timeouts).  Note: this test is dependent on the Ajax request taking a bit of time, since if it doesn't it is possible for the button to be re-enabled before the find of the disabled button happens